# How to fix npm install react list filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I get an error while installing react-list-filter use npm (npm install react-list-filter), this is error messages in my console :

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for awesomplete@1.0.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'react-list-filter'
npm ERR! notarget 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/andrew/.npm/_logs/2017-09-26T08_01_47_125Z-debug.log
```

I try to install awesomplete, but still, error when I install react-list-filter, please anyone help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was their bug, and it was listed on an issue a year ago

https://github.com/rauljordan/react-list-filter/issues/1

It's not likely to be fixed, you probably need to fork their repository and change their dependency on `awesomplate` version

Comment: I have changed awesomplete version to 1.1.0, but when I install use npm (npm install react-list-filter), I get same error. . .what's next .?@James Maa